# Format a number as phone number in MS Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, microsoft-ajax

How to format a number as phone number (e.g. (45)879-2658 ) using MS Ajax formatting.

In C#, i can format this number using  {0:(###)###-####} .

But not sure how to achieve this format in MS Ajax for an integer.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What do you mean by MS Ajax? Are you making ana AJAX request and want the string response to be in that format?

Comment: No. need to format based on MicrosoftAjax.js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know C#, this is how you can do picture formatting in javascript:

```
format = "(###)###-####"
input = 1234567890
formatted = format.replace(/#/g, [].shift.bind(String(input).split("")))
// result: "(123)456-7890"
```

To handle strings shorter than a picture, try this slightly more verbose code:

```
chars = String(input).split("")
formatted = format.replace(/#/g, function() { return chars.shift() || "" })
```

Comment: Note: [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Browser_compatibility) for `.bind()`.

Comment: Thanks @thg435!. But if a digit is lesser than 10 digits , i am getting 'undefined' at the end.